# Old/retro anime or cartoon with robots (visuals inside)

Tags: story-identification, anime, robots, cartoon, steampunk

There is this very vague memory of some kind of anime or cartoon from my childhood and I really want to recall it. Everything I remember about it is the style of environment and surroundings that is similar to this picture (it's from a music video so it's irrelevant):

[image]

When I saw this picture it immediately reminded me of that cartoon or anime. I'm trying to remember so I think it had visuals like this? I think the plot had to do something with robots. I know there is very little information but if someone would suggest something out of it I would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Please give us the music video's name; maybe someone compared the cartoon you're looking for with it as well, and it could be searched for on the vast Internet :) It would also be helpful if you could browse through [that list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if it triggers any more memories you could [edit] in.

Comment: And for what it's worth, robots+moss+steampunk rings [_Castle in the Sky_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McM0_YHDm5A) to my ears, but as of now the question is too terse to flesh that out into an actual answer, hence this being a comment.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: This is visually similar to scenes from [Feel Good Inc.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyHNuVaZJ-k&feature=youtu.be&t=163), [the Animatrix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0K6Cb1ZoG4&feature=youtu.be&t=152) (warning NSFW - Gory) and others

Comment: Letting us know when you saw this would probably narrow the field considerably (I'll throw *Serial Experiments Lain* into the consideration mix, just because I know that was fairly popular at one point)

Comment: The Animatrix looks a lot like something I saw actually! If someone can point out a cartoon movie or anime/OVA like this I think it could be something I'm looking for? I feel like I saw it long time ago it would be like 10-15 years ago!

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but the actual image appears to be from an illustrator named Torigoe Takumi.  I know this image just reminds the poster of a movie but I thought it would not hurt to add.

Comment: @Noelle what do you mean, an OVA/anime? Something similar to Animatrix, or the whole Animatrix clips?

Comment: sound like Now and Then ?or this show have boy and girl main characters ??

Comment: It would be useful to know how much time ago you watched it... My guess is [Neon Genesis Evangelion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_Genesis_Evangelion) (the girl somehow reminds me of Asuka and also the lighting of the scene somehow looks similar)

Comment: The first thing your post and image remind me of is the 2001 anime film [Metropolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis_(2001_film)).